# Spring Integration MessageBuilder getSequenceDetails class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.util.List

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I'm using Spring Integration in my Spring Boot project.

My spring boot application gives error like this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.util.List (java.lang.String and java.util.List are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder.getSequenceDetails(MessageBuilder.java:206)
    at org.springframework.integration.support.AbstractIntegrationMessageBuilder.popSequenceDetails(AbstractIntegrationMessageBuilder.java:87)
    at org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder.popSequenceDetails(MessageBuilder.java:238)
    at org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder.popSequenceDetails(MessageBuilder.java:49)
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.completeGroup(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:843)
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.processMessageForGroup(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:498)
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:471)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:170)
    ... 129 more
```

I'm not using sequenceDetails header anywhere and It looks like Spring Integrations puts this itself and now gives exception.

I debugged and saw that the sequenceDetails header like this:

sequenceDetails [[67eea8d9-3295-4ea1-b85e-9ef970298986, 0, 0]]

Why do I face this error? Please tell me what you want to see from my project to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do some serialization before that aggregator so `List<List<Object>>` value for `IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.SEQUENCE_DETAILS` header is converted to string somehow. Probably just via simple `toString()`.

First of all you may not populate such a headers information via `applySequence=false` on the splitter upstream.

Secondly you may disable popping sequence details on the aggregator level.
See its respective property:

```
/**
 * Perform a
 * {@link org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder#popSequenceDetails()}
 * for output message or not. Default to true. This option removes the sequence
 * information added by the nearest upstream component with {@code applySequence=true}
 * (for example splitter).
 * @param popSequence the boolean flag to use.
 * @since 5.1
 */
public void setPopSequence(boolean popSequence) {
```

Or you can convert that string back to `List<List<Object>>` from string via some header enricher in between.

It is really unusual to see such a header be converted to string. I'm really curious how that happened in your use-case. Perhaps we may some automation on the framework level if we would know more about your scenario.